# Can't fire click event after transform div into slick slider

Tags: jquery, html, slick.js

I have a div with the next structure

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="limiter"></div>
   <div class="limiter"></div>
   <div class="limiter"></div>
   <div class="limiter"></div>
   <div class="limiter"></div>
</div>
```

When using a desktop, this div is a simple flexbox but when using a mobile device, it is transformed to a Slick Slider. The thing is that the "limiter" class fires a function using jquery

```
$(".limiter").click(function(){
   console.log('this is a test')
})
```

But after I transform to a Slick Slider, this function stop working. It doesn't give any console error.
I already tried to change the z-index, to keep the js code and the html in the same file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information. Sounds like an issue with the way you attach the event listener.

Comment: It's just an example because the code is huge and this is working on desktop so I guess the problem is the slider.

Comment: An irrelevant example isn't going to help us answer your question. Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).